# declaring qtcpsocket class object as global

Tags: qt

I am working on qt to develop a socket programming.i am posting the code here.
"mainwindow.h"

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}
static void handler(int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *uc);

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    QTcpSocket *socket;
    void timer();
    void config();


private slots:
    void newconnection();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QTcpServer *server; 

};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

"mainwindow.cpp"

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    static char i;
    ui->setupUi(this);
    sock=socket;
    //    if(!i)
    //    {
    //        connect(ui->start_button,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(config()));
    //    }
    //    i=1;
    qDebug()<<i;
}
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
void MainWindow ::newconnection()
{
    static int i;
    socket=server->nextPendingConnection();
    //connect(socket,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(timer_data_recieve()));
    qDebug()<<"new connection";
    qDebug()<<"server is reading..."<<socket->bytesAvailable();
    qDebug()<<socket->readAll();
    //time->start(1000);   //QT timer started
    if(!i)
        timer();
    i=1;
}
void MainWindow::timer()
{
    timer_t t_id;
    struct sigaction sa;
    struct sigaction arg;
    struct sigevent s_evnt;
    struct itimerspec timer;
    /* Establish handler for notification signal */
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sa.sa_sigaction = handler;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    s_evnt.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
    s_evnt.sigev_signo = SIGRTMAX;
    s_evnt.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &t_id;
    if (sigaction(SIGRTMAX, &sa,NULL) == -1)
    {
        perror("sigaction");
    }
    //==============timer vlaues==============
    timer.it_value.tv_sec=0;
    timer.it_value.tv_nsec=20000000;
    timer.it_interval.tv_sec=0;
    timer.it_interval.tv_nsec=20000000;
    if(timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME,&s_evnt,&t_id)==-1);
    perror("timer create");
    if(timer_settime(t_id,0,&timer,NULL)==-1)
        perror("timer_set_time");
}
void MainWindow::config()
{
    //time=new QTimer(this);
    server=new QTcpServer(this);
    socket=new QTcpSocket(this);
    connect(server,SIGNAL(newConnection()),this,SLOT(newconnection()));
    // connect(time,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(timer_data_sending()));
    if(server->listen(QHostAddress::LocalHost,600))
    {
        qDebug()<<"server started";
    }
    else
        qDebug()<<"server not started";
    qDebug()<<MainWindow::server->errorString();
}
static void handler(int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *uc)
{
    // MainWindow w;
    qDebug("in handler");
    // MainWindow *s = static_cast<MainWindow*>(&w);
    static char first_call=1;
    static unsigned sec;
    static long nsec;
    struct timespec start;
    struct timespec curr;
    if (first_call) {
        first_call = 0;
        if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start) == -1)
            perror("clock_gettime");
    }
    if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &curr) == -1)
        perror("clock_gettime");
    sec = (curr.tv_sec - start.tv_sec);
    nsec = (curr.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec);
    if (nsec < 0)
    {
        sec--;
        nsec += 1000000000;
    }
    start = curr;

}
```

"main.cpp"

```
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        QApplication a(argc, argv);
        MainWindow w;
        w.show();
        w.config();
       return a.exec();
    }
```

here evrything is working fine about handler.
but if want to access the handler data to socket to send to client,one way is to declare socket is global.but how to decalre globally to access in mainwindow member functions and as well as in handler?
please suggest me.it is very important to me .please don't avoid it.
NOTE:qtimer is not neded here

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Singletone Design Pattern` architecture for your `TCP Socket` class. You need to create class that `extends` `QTcpSocket`. So you will create only one object and access the same globally using `get_instance()` method, as it is `public static` in this design pattern. You can go through [Singleton design pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/singleton_pattern.htm)

Comment: is it better to use singlton or Q_GLOBAL_OBJECT.And if i use singlton can i access the instance in handler and as well as mainwindow?

Comment: @RajSekhar : yeah you can, you need to add `.h` files of `singletone` class in  `.cpp` where you want to use `SingleTone` instance

Comment: I saw that singleton example.but can you plese tell me which part to add where in my project.

Comment: @RajSekhar: create new class for Socket which will extent  `QTCPSocket` and then you will have `mysocket.h` and `mysocket.cpp` of that new class with Singletone method to get instance of that Class. To access that instance you need to add `mysocket.h` in `mainwindow.h` in your project

Comment: class sock:public QTcpSocket
{
private:
    sock(){}

    //Get the only object available
public:
    static QTcpSocket* getInstance()
    {
         QTcpSocket *instance = new QTcpSocket;
        return instance;
    }
};

Comment: @RajSekhar: exactly !!

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#qmlRegisterSingletonType) contains a good example about how to implement a Singleton and export it from C++ to QML.